# "Learn Python The Hard Way" Ex24.py

Tags: python

On the website for "Learn Python The Hard Way" there is exercise 24 which I do not understand. Here is the code that the author wanted me to write down.

```
print "Let's practice everything."
print 'You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

poem = """
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
"""

print "--------------"
print poem
print "--------------"


five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
print "This should be five: %s" % five

def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)

start_point = start_point / 10

print "We can also do that this way:"
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

This is the result:

```
$ python ex24.py
Let's practice everything.
You'd need to know 'bout escapes with \ that do
 newlines and   tabs.
--------------

       The lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern
 the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation

              where there is none.

--------------
This should be five: 5
With a starting point of: 10000
We'd have 5000000 beans, 5000 jars, and 50 crates.
We can also do that this way:
We'd have 500000 beans, 500 jars, and 5 crates.
```

Does this mean that the start_point variable replaced the `started` variable of the function? Also, is there a specific name for the variable in the ()parenthesis of a function? To clarify, in `secretformula(started)`, would `started` just be a regular variable or have a separate name. Sorry if this is obvious(I'm a noob).

Comment: `started` is a separate variable name, you could choose whatever name you wanted for it. What happens, behind the scenes, is that the value of `start_point` is assigned to the `started` variable upon the invocation of the `secret_formula` function.

Comment: Was there not a previous lesson on functions?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the first code block there is no need for the indent after then 1st line :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the start_point variable replaced the "started" variable of the function?

That's how parameters work, yes. But rather you'd say, `started` was assigned the value of `start_point`.

> is there a specific name for the variable in the ()parenthesis of a function

Not in the code, no. The name only improves readability to the developer

> in "secretformula(started)", would "started" just be a regular variable or have a separate name

It's a parameter in that quote, it's a variable during `secret_formula(start_point)`